# Edit text save text after reopen fragment

Tags: android, android-edittext

Hi all  i have a problem with edit text in frament. This elemtn save text after reopening this fragment. It can reproduce if i do this steps
open activity -> open FragmentA ->open FragmentB (with edittext in it)->backPress(and open again FragmentA) -> open FragmentB (again)
After this steps if i am typed before some text its  fill it again. I am add this in code: `writeReviewText.setText("");`  and in xml : `android:text=""` but nothing helps. It`s look like state of fragment is saves.
Here the code of xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/app_bar_gradient"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/greyReview">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollReview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/recomendRev"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/leftIb"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:src="@drawable/review_recomend_left_selector" />

                    <LinearLayout

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:alpha="0.5"
                            android:src="@drawable/good" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/leftTv"
                            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:text="@string/recomend"
                            android:textColor="@color/fiolet" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/noRecomendRev"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/rightIb"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:src="@drawable/review_recomend_right_selector" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:alpha="0.5"
                            android:src="@drawable/bad" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/rightTv"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:text="@string/dontRecomended"
                            android:textColor="@color/fiolet" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/writeReviewText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:hint="@string/dummyReview"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:maxLength="2000"
                android:text=""
                android:maxLines="4" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:background="@color/darkGreyReview">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/photosDummy"
                    layout="@layout/add_photo_dummy"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </include>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/photosRv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </FrameLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here a code of my fragment class:

```
public class WriteReviewFragment extends Fragment implements Constants, View.OnClickListener, ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener, CameraInterface {
MainActivity mActivity;
View self;
EditText writeReviewText;

public int GetPixelFromDips(float pixels) {
    // Get the screen's density scale
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
    return (int) (pixels * scale + 0.5f);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreateView");
    self = inflater.inflate(R.layout.write_review_layout, container, false);
    mActivity = ((MainActivity) getActivity());
    font = DialogsHelper.getRLight(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    user = mActivity.getUser();
    width = DialogsHelper.getDisplayWidth(mActivity);
    currentlocale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
    return self;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onViewCreated");
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Toolbar tv = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    TextView tbTv = (TextView) tv.findViewById(R.id.tolbarTv);
    TextView post = (TextView) tv.findViewById(R.id.post);
    back = (ImageView) tv.findViewById(R.id.back);
    post.setTypeface(font);
    tbTv.setTypeface(font);

    tags = (RecipientEditTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.chipsView);
    tags.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
    tags.setAdapter(new BaseRecipientAdapter(getActivity()));

    tags.setTypeface(font);
    musicExLv = (ExpandableListView) self.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
    peopleAVGExLv = (ExpandableListView) self.findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewAVG);
    peopleIm = (ImageView) self.findViewById(R.id.peopleIm);
    musicIm = (ImageView) self.findViewById(R.id.musicIm);
    photosDummy = (RelativeLayout) self.findViewById(R.id.photosDummy);
    photosRv = (RecyclerView) self.findViewById(R.id.photosRv);
    avgpeople = (TextView) self.findViewById(R.id.avgpeople);
    musictype = (TextView) self.findViewById(R.id.musictype);
    faceControl = (TextView) self.findViewById(R.id.faceControl);
    dresCode = (TextView) self.findViewById(R.id.dresCode);
    details = (TextView) self.findViewById(R.id.details);
    tagsTv = (TextView) self.findViewById(R.id.tags);
    rightTv = (TextView) self.findViewById(R.id.rightTv);
    leftTv = (TextView) self.findViewById(R.id.leftTv);
    writeReviewText = (EditText) self.findViewById(R.id.writeReviewText);
    noRecomendRev = (ImageButton) self.findViewById(R.id.rightIb);
    recomendRev = (ImageButton) self.findViewById(R.id.leftIb);

    dresleftIb = (ImageButton) self.findViewById(R.id.dresleftIb);
    dresRightIb = (ImageButton) self.findViewById(R.id.dresRightIb);
    faceleftIb = (ImageButton) self.findViewById(R.id.faceleftIb);
    faceRightIb = (ImageButton) self.findViewById(R.id.faceRightIb);
    faceRightTv = (TextView) self.findViewById(R.id.faceRightTv);
    faceleftTv = (TextView) self.findViewById(R.id.faceleftTv);
    dresrightTv = (TextView) self.findViewById(R.id.dresrightTv);
    dresleftTv = (TextView) self.findViewById(R.id.dresleftTv);

    post.setOnClickListener(this);
    back.setOnClickListener(this);
    dresleftIb.setOnClickListener(this);
    dresRightIb.setOnClickListener(this);
    faceleftIb.setOnClickListener(this);
    faceRightIb.setOnClickListener(this);
    noRecomendRev.setOnClickListener(this);
    recomendRev.setOnClickListener(this);
    photosDummy.setOnClickListener(this);
    peopleIm.setOnClickListener(this);
    musicIm.setOnClickListener(this);
    writeReviewText.setTypeface(font);
    avgpeople.setTypeface(font);
    musictype.setTypeface(font);
    faceControl.setTypeface(font);
    dresCode.setTypeface(font);
    details.setTypeface(font);
    tagsTv.setTypeface(font);
    rightTv.setTypeface(font);
    leftTv.setTypeface(font);
    faceRightTv.setTypeface(font);
    faceleftTv.setTypeface(font);
    dresrightTv.setTypeface(font);
    dresleftTv.setTypeface(font);

    StaggeredGridLayoutManager sglm = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    photosRv.setLayoutManager(sglm);

    //set same size as images preview
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, width / screenPart);
    Log.e(TAG, "photosDummy" + (width / screenPart));
    photosDummy.setLayoutParams(lp);


    if (getArguments() != null) {
        Bundle b = getArguments();
        if (b.containsKey("foursquare_id")) {
            foursquare_id = b.getString("foursquare_id").toString();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "FSQ Id is empty, you can`t post anything", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    //change state of arrow marker
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        musicExLv.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(width - GetPixelFromDips(30), width - GetPixelFromDips(10));
        peopleAVGExLv.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(width - GetPixelFromDips(30), width - GetPixelFromDips(10));
    } else {
        musicExLv.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetPixelFromDips(30), width - GetPixelFromDips(10));
        peopleAVGExLv.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetPixelFromDips(30), width - GetPixelFromDips(10));
    }
    prepareMusicList();
    preparePeopleList();
    writeReviewText.setText("");
    writeReviewText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            reviewAdd.setReview_text(s.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

And here code how i am open fragment in activity:

```
        public void SetCurentFragment(final int index, int direction, boolean addToBackStack, int type, Bundle bundle) {

    if (currentIndex != 5) {
        previosIndex = currentIndex;
    }
    if (index == 1 || index == 2)
        DeleteAllFragmentsBackstack();// need for detect if google map is initialize and already in backstack

    Fragment fragment; 
    fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ReadReviewFragment.class.getClass().getSimpleName());
    if (fragment == null) {
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = fragmentArray[index];
        }
    } else {
        fragment = fragmentArray[index];
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "Open fragment is " + fragment);
    if (fragment.getArguments() != null) {
        fragment.getArguments().clear(); //for clear arguments if they saved from previous open of fragment(happens when open photos fragment)
    }
    if (bundle != null) {
        if (fragment.getArguments() == null) {
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        } else {
            fragment.getArguments().clear(); 
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        }
    }

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    if (addToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getTag());
    } else {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    Log.e(TAG, "Transaction commit");
    currentIndex = index;
    if (index == 0 || index == 1 || index == 2) {
        SetVisualTabs(index);
    }

}
```

I am debug my code and bundle is empty when i am open FragmentB. And fragmentArray its array of fragments like:

```
 public final Fragment[] fragmentArray = new Fragment[]{
        new FragmentA(),//0
        new FragmentB(),//1
```

Comment: The editText is filled because the fragment is not being recreated, it's being grabbed from the backstack with it's corresponding state and modifications. If you want a new clear fragment, remove the current fragment from the backstack and create a new one

Comment: #Ricardo you meen do this:

 FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.remove(mSomeFragment);
                transaction.commit();

Comment: Do you fixed this problem?